# Upload a folder full of files (static html and assets) to the private files folder when creating a node

Tags: 7, users

I need to be able to upload a folder full of files (static html and assets) when creating a new node and then to output a link to the index.html file in the uploaded folder.

They files from a learning modules created by a third party tool and exported as static HTML so each new node is a listing for a new learning module.

**Critically all of this needs to be uploaded to the private files directory so only logged in users can see the contents.**

Currently when I manually upload to the private files and link to the static html at that location (displaying the page inside a lightbox) I get the following Apache error:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Note:  this is an Apache 500 error. I have uploaded the index.html file directly to the private files folder using sftp so I'm guessing when I load it up in a lightbox window as above apache isn't letting me access it.

Comment: This looks like an Apache 500 error rather than the Drupal access denied message. You might want to `chmod` and update the file permission on server?

Comment: Yeah this is an Apache 500 error. I have uploaded the index.html file directly to the private files folder using sftp so I'm guessing when I load it up in a lightbox window as above apache isn't letting me access it.

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase this question so I've updated above.

Comment: Have you tried the file_save_upload function? https://api.drupal.org/comment/26628#comment-26628

Comment: Looks like that will only help with individual files

Comment: If you uploaded with sftp and than the server can't write it, that can mean the server (apache) has a different user space where it runs, and that user can't overwrite your sftp's user's file, maybe you need to change the user and the user group too on those files. However if you can upload and overwrite the files one-by-one than this is not your case.